# Bootstrapping p values in linear regression in R

Tags: bootstrap

Can someone help me with a code how to bootstrap p values in R using Boot or boot package?

regCSS30 <- dyn$lm(lag(eval(parse(text="HV")),-30) ~ lag((eval(parse(text="CSS30"))),0), data=window(ts_CM30, 1975, 2015))

My regression is of the following type, how can I bootstrap p-values?

Thank you very much.